# EF Core. Иерархические данные. Не создает таблицу

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Не первая БД, но уткнулся в проблему, и не могу ее понять.

Модель:

```
public class TemplateWork
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Родительский объект
        /// </summary>
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public TemplateWork? Parent { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public IEnumerable<TemplateWork> Stages { get; set; }

        public TemplateWork() => Stages = new List<TemplateWork>(); 
    }
```

Конфигурация модели:

```
public class TemplateWorkEFConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TemplateWork>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TemplateWork> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("TemplateWorks");

        builder
            .HasOne(o => o.Parent)
            .WithMany(s => s.Stages)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.ParentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);            
    }

}
```

BDContext

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDBContext()            
        {           
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; } = null!;
        public DbSet<TemplateWork> TemplateWorks { get; set; } = null!;

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) 
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.............");             
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TemplateWorkEFConfiguration());
        }
   }
```

Таблица не создается. Мало того, когда включаю public DbSet TemplateWorks никакая таблица не создается, без нее все работает.
При выполнении исключений не возникает.
Другие связанные модели (правда на 2 таблицы) - отрабатывают.
Помогите разобраться....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Включаем логирование. Простейший способ сделать это - добавить строку в `OnConfiguring`:

```
optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
```

И мне было любезно выведено сообщение:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_TemplateWorks_TemplateWorks_ParentId' on table 'TemplateWorks' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Я исправил код в `Configure` на:

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

И таблица успешно создалась.